# prototype is not saves to localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have factory for the date:

```
angular.module('app').factory('DateFactory', function($filter) {
  var date = function() {
    this.value = null;
    this.format = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
    this.opened = false;
  };

  date.prototype.today = function() {
    this.value = new Date().getTime();
  };

  date.prototype.clear = function() {
    this.value = null;
  };

  date.prototype.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    this.opened = true;
  };

  return new date();
});
```

And I have date object.

```
{
 name: 'date',
 id: 'date1'
}
```

At start I wanna to add this (factory) propertys to this object. Then I save this file to localstorage and when I restart my page it loading from localstorage. Propertys like name, id, value, format and opened is saved and loaded right, but prototype changes not saves. So I think I need to call factory again but only for prototype, not for value, format and opened.. Things like:
`dateObj.__proto__.today = DateFactory.prototype.today;` not working, where I'm wrong?

Comment: You cannot save functions. Also `.factory` is for single instances, so `prototype` doesn't make much sense here. A better description of your use case would be helpful.